# Where to perform UI element styling on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS dev, and have read a bunch of tutorials and video series. I come from a Windows background, and wanted to know, if I wanted to create a custom "styled" button, what function does one override in a view controller to make ui changes such as rounding the button's edges. etc.
What I have done so far is added a button with an image, insets, constraints, background color, and just need to round the edges now, which I am doing by the overriding the loadView function.

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    loginButton.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commented this on your other post -- if you are using Xcode 6, there are some new properties that will allow you to display changes to UI elements live (on storyboard).

To quote this tutorial on weheartswift.com, https://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/

"**IBInspectable** exposes class properties in the interface builder Attribute Inspector, and **IBDesignable** updates the view in realtime!"

If you take a look at the video at the bottom of that page, it shows some examples with buttons that seem to be exactly what you are looking for.